# How to randomly choose items from an array ?

Tags: php, random

I have an array of 50 items and I would like to choose 5 of them randomly and get an array back. Is there a function for this?

Comment: What 50 numbers? Are they 50 known numbers to choose 5 from, or are you just looking to select 5 (unique) numbers within a certain range?

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it's a good question (albeit somewhat poorly worded, but still).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the items in an array and use:

```
$selectrand = array_rand($arrayname, 5);
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that the randomness of this function is somewhat faulty... The article recommended shuffling the array and then calling any nth element.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$randomnumber = (rand()%$num);
```